# Question about Theorem 15.0.2 from David Ulrich's Complex Made Simple

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\textbf{Theorem 15.0.1}$. Suppose that $\phi \in Aut(\mathbb{D})$ is not the identity. Then, if $\phi$ is elliptic then $\phi$ is conjugate to a rotation: There exists a complex number $\alpha \neq 1$ with $|a| = 1$ such that $\phi$ is conjugate to $\psi$, where $\psi(z) = \alpha z \,\, (z \in \mathbb{D})$.

> $\textbf{Theorem 15.0.2}$. Suppose that $\phi \in Aut(\mathbb{D})$.
> If $\phi$ is either elliptic of finite order, parabolic, or hyperbolic, there exists a bounded nonconstant $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ such that $f \circ\phi=f$ and, if $\phi$ is elliptic of infinite order and $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ with $f \circ \phi = f$, then $f$ is constant.

I don't understand very good the proof of Theorem 15.0.2. It says that:

Suppose first that $\phi$ is elliptic. The previous theorem shows that we may assume that $\phi$ is a rotation: $\phi(z) = \alpha z$, where $|\alpha| = 1$.
$\color{red}{\text{Why we may assume this?}}$

...

On the other hand, if $\phi$ has infinite order then the powers of $\alpha$ are dense in the unit circle, so that if $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ and $f \circ \phi = f$ then $f$ must be constant. $\color{red}{\text{How results this from the fact that powers of $\alpha$ are dense in unit circle and f is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$?}}$